# Android SSL validation does not work below Android5.0

Tags: android, ssl, okhttp

I'm using Okhttp as my network utility now. I found a strange issue that I can't verify ssl connection(under dev) on devices below Android 5.0, the log printed `SSL handshake aborted`, which does not exist over API21.

Following is the code:

```
public class CertificationUtils {

public static X509TrustManager x509TrustManager;

public static SSLContext sslContext = null;

public static HostnameVerifier DO_NOT_VERIFY;

public static void init(){

    x509TrustManager = new X509TrustManager() {
        @Override
        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {

        }

        @Override
        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s) throws CertificateException {

        }

        @Override
        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            X509Certificate[] x509Certificates = new X509Certificate[0];
            return x509Certificates;
        }

    };

    try {
        sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");

        sslContext.init(null, new TrustManager[]{x509TrustManager}, new SecureRandom());

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (KeyManagementException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    DO_NOT_VERIFY = new HostnameVerifier() {
        @Override
        public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
            return true;
        }
    };

}
```

}

Okhttp side:

```
CertificationUtils.init();

client = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
.sslSocketFactory(CertificationUtils.sslContext.getSocketFactory(), CertificationUtils.x509TrustManager)                     
.hostnameVerifier(CertificationUtils.DO_NOT_VERIFY).build();
```

Could anyone tell me what's wrong?

Comment: Are you sure that it is related to the validation of the certificate at all? "SSL handshake aborted" can be caused by the server aborting the handshake because it does not like the ciphers or similar offered by the client. In this case this is done before any certificate was send and therefore before validation. Apart from that "validation does not work" is misleading because you explicitly disable validation (bad!).

Comment: Your words make a lot of sense, I suspected the possibilty of server side doing wrong too, but I still can't understand why the higer API can pass the validation while the lower can't. @SteffenUllrich

Comment: It might be that both would pass the validation but the lower API does not even reach it because of handshake errors. This could be problems with different ciphers, supported protocols, SNI or not etc. If this would be a public server you are trying to reach one maybe could have a close look which behavior could be the problem.